# Pushing New Provision Profiles

Tags: ios, osx-mavericks, mdm

I just have a quick question before I dive in...

My Ad-Hoc in house app has and expired provision profile, I know how to renew it and download a new one.
My question is there a method for pushing the new/updated provision profile to the the device. I don't physically have the device with me, it is managed by Apples MDM server using profile manager.

Im trying not to use mail, web clips, Bookmarks. Because I'm Restricting Safari access.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In MDM solutions yes there are ways to push provisioning profiles as well. For profile manager you may follow [this link](http://help.apple.com/profilemanager/mac/10.7/#apd5C967281-34CD-40C6-AA39-6DBDAD6E201B)

Comment: The link you refer to concerns 'configuration profiles', not 'provisioning profiles', AFAICT. I have not found a way to push a provisioning profile from Profile Manager except when it's in an app bundle.

Comment: Provisioning profiles are also possible. Please watch the Apple WWDC videos on this. They describes this.

Comment: Do you happen to know which WWDC video that is? Was it 2013? When I try to search the videos, even the titles of the videos, I can never find what I'm looking for. I try to keep notes on the ones I've seen, but it would be great if there was a subject index to the videos.

Comment: Watch the 2010 session 108